# Simple factory - checking data correctness

Tags: java

I have `Month` class which contains some data eg. `number`, `number of days` etc. I would like to create this class instance simply. I decided to create simple factory which contains months data and returns ready object. My question is where to check data correctness eg. January has 31 days and a couple others... Should `Month` class checks that data is correct or `Factory` should be responsible for it? (in this case we can create `Month` object with invalid data)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Month class should check this itself. It's always best practice to have the logic that is dependent only on the class in the class itself. Otherwise if someone else uses your application and instantiates a Month object without using the factory it will work, but it won't be what you as the designer intended.

You can handle an error however you like it, but I would do it in the constructor and then throw an error if someone tries instantiating it with invalid parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't reinvent calendar classes! Someone has already done it for you. Take a look at [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the Java 8 package [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). This are good starting points to learn how classes like `Month` should be designed.

The concepts of *month* and *day of month* shouldn't be mixed within a single class. Because how many days a month has depends on the year and the calendar system. The validation for *invalid number of days* should be done when you create a *date* from *day of month*, *month* and *year*. So it is part of the construction process of a *date* object.

This looks strange:

```
Month january = Month.newMonth(31);
```

The factory method which creates a `Month` object from an `int` should check if the parameter is in the range from 1 (January) to 12 (December) and return an enum representing the concrete month.

This is what I would expect:

```
Month january = Month.newMonth(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should validate the parameters before passing them in a constructor.

However a static factory method might not be the best place to validate input, if the input is dynamic and NOT done by you.

If you just want to make sure the compiler warns you if you use invalid parameters, you could throw a checked exception like this:

```
public static final Month newMonth(int numberOfDays) {
if(numberOfDays > 31 || numberOfDays < 28) {
throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid numberOfDays");
}
return new Month(numberOfDays);
}
```

Either way, in my opinion, you should not go the try...catch way or make the constructor validate anything as it makes your code a lot less readable and also could break a lot of other code if you change your validation method.